# Is this a local or global variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, global, local

I am a beginner at using JS, right now I am working on a project, where I have to explain which global and local variables I have used, I am not sure which variables are global and which are local. I know that a variable existing inside a function is a local variable, but I have the following:

```
onload=function(){
    var ctx=document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
};
```

Is my variable `ctx` inside the function? I am not sure, since I've used `onload`, I don't know if `ctx` is a global or local variable?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the anonymous function is assigned to. What matters is that a variable is declared within a function scope.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a function to a variable (assigning to a variable makes no difference, it still creates the scope even if the function is not assigned), that gives `ctx` a functional scope. Anonymous functions are no different scope wise than a named function

Comment: "You are assigning a function to a variable, that gives ctx a functional scope" --- it's not entirely correct phrase. Even if you are not assigning a function to anything - it still creates a scope.

Comment: @zerkms this was more specific to the example, but I agree that could be worded better. Just a moment

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful! I have another question, I have the following:

    var bat={ x: 100, y: 100, h: 25 };

That gives me the varibles bat.x, bat.y and bat.h, right? And they are global variables, right?

Comment: @user3742947 first question yes, the second question: it depends on where `bat` is defined and easy way to find out is using `use strict` which doesn't like globals

Comment: @user3742947: To be clear, `x`, `y` and `h` are not variables at all. They are properties of the object referenced by the `bat` variable.

Answer (score 1):

`ctx` is inside a function, that means it's not a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is *declared* inside of a function. That means the *scope* of the variable is the function, which makes it local, correct. Look for where the `var` declaration is.

Global variables are accessible from anywhere in the program, and have the same life cycle as the rest of the code. They are declared outside of any function scope.

Comment: This was very helpful! Will you also help me with this:
I have the following: 
var bat={ x: 100, y: 100, h: 25 }; 
That gives me the varibles bat.x, bat.y and bat.h, right? And they are global variables, right?

Comment: well bat is a global variable(a struct) if it is defined outside any function and x,y and h are all members of the bat struct which makes them accessible where bat is accessible by using bat.x,bat.y,bat.h. kindly consult the link in my answer above for examples on global variables. Hope that helps

Comment: `bat` is a global variable. `x`,`y` and `h` are all local variables belonging to `bat`.

Answer (score 0):

Any variable created inside a function is a local variable. That mean it would only be present until you are inside the function i.e. While the function is being executed and won't be accessible from outside. And any variable declared outside a function is a global function as it can be easily accessed inside the function. So in your case as your variable `ctx` has been declared inside a function hence it is local variable. Kindly see the link below for more detail on global variables

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable